# when to use validation rule & trigger's add error method

Tags: apex, trigger, validation-rule, adderror

what is the difference between validation rule & triggers add error method? mens when I can use validation rule & when use adderror method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use either to achieve the same effect. It's usually more a matter of preference. If you *can* use a validation rule, you *should*, but if the validation rule would be too complicated, or impossible to write (such as checking unrelated records for data), then use Apex Code. We generally call this the "configuration before code" rule of thumb. However, there are some times when using code instead of validation rules are helpful, like if you want to disable the validation via code to bypass the logic when updating records in code.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take an example

Suppose you have to validate Zip code, just think what will you use?
 - yes validation rule, you can validate it in before trigger as well, but it is not a good approach to validate the things in triggers which are achievable using validation rule.

Now second example suppose while creating an opportunity you have to validate if corresponding account has contact(s) then and then opportunity should be created, What will you do?

Using validation you can't check whether account has contact or not, so in this case you will use before trigger.

So remember when you need to calculate something by querying that time validate using before trigger addError().